# java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jbossws

I seemed to get the following exception when trying to deploy my application:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of     IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at java.util.List
    at private java.util.List     foobar.alkohol.register.webservice.jaxws.GetRelationsFromPersonResponse._return
    at     foobar.alkohol.register.webservice.jaxws.GetRelationsFromPersonResponse
java.util.List does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.List
        at private java.util.List foobar.alkohol.register.webservice.jaxws.GetRelationsFromPersonResponse._return
    at     foobar.alkohol.register.webservice.jaxws.GetRelationsFromPersonResponse
```

**My code worked just well until I changed the return type from List to List<List<RelationCanonical>>**

Here is the partial webservice:

```
@Name("relationService")
@Stateless
@WebService(name = "RelationService", serviceName = "RelationService")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class RelationService implements RelationServiceLocal {

    private boolean login(String username, String password) {
        Identity.instance().setUsername(username);
        Identity.instance().setPassword(password);
        Identity.instance().login();
        return Identity.instance().isLoggedIn();
    }

    private boolean logout() {
        Identity.instance().logout();
        return !Identity.instance().isLoggedIn();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public List<List<RelationCanonical>> getRelationsFromPerson(@WebParam(name = "username")
    String username, @WebParam(name = "password")
    String password, @WebParam(name = "foedselsnummer")
    String... foedselsnummer) {

......
......
......
}
```

**I have also tried by removing the @SOAPBinding and trying default, but the same result occurs.
Appreciate any help**

**UPDATE**

I want to note out something. I changed all List to ArrayList, and then it compiled. The reason why I say compiled and not worked is because it behaves strange. I get an Object of type: 
RelationServiceStub.ArrayList
but the object has no get methods or does not behave as a List either. I also tried to cast it to a List but that didnt work.

Note that this is after I have used Axis 2 and wsdl2java So yes, now it compiles, but I dont know how to get the data out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In my understanding, you will not be able to process a plain `List` via JAXB, as JAXB has no idea how to transform that into XML.

Instead, you will need to define a JAXB type which holds a `List<RelationCanonical>` (I'll call it `Type1`), and another one to hold a list of those types, in turn (as you're dealing with a `List<List<...>>`; I'll call this type `Type2`).

The result could then be an XML ouput like this:

```
<Type2 ...>
    <Type1 ...>
        <RelationCanonical ...> ... </RelationCanonical>
        <RelationCanonical ...> ... </RelationCanonical>
        ...
    </Type1>
    <Type1>
        <RelationCanonical ...> ... </RelationCanonical>
        <RelationCanonical ...> ... </RelationCanonical>
        ...
    </Type1>
    ...
</Type2>
```

Without the two enclosing JAXB-annotated types, the JAXB processor has no idea what markup to generate, and thus fails.

--Edit:

What I mean should look somewhat like this:

```
@XmlType
public class Type1{

    private List<RelationCanonical> relations;

    @XmlElement
    public List<RelationCanonical> getRelations(){
        return this.relations;
    }

    public void setRelations(List<RelationCanonical> relations){
        this.relations = relations;
    }
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Type2{

    private List<Type1> type1s;

    @XmlElement
    public List<Type1> getType1s(){
        return this.type1s;
    }

    public void setType1s(List<Type1> type1s){
        this.type1s= type1s;
    }
}
```

You should also check out the [JAXB section in the J5EE tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnazf.html) and the [Unofficial JAXB Guide](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html).

Answer (score 8):

If that suits your purpose you can always define an array like this:

```
YourType[]
```

JAXB can certainly figure out what that is and you should be able to immediatly use it client side. I would also recommend you to do it that way, since you should not be able to modify the array retrieved from a server via a List but via methods provided by the web service

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for any class.

```
return items.size() > 0 ? items.toArray((Object[]) Array.newInstance(
            items.get(0).getClass(), 0)) : new Object[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error message than yours (in French):

> java.util.List est une interface et JAXB ne peut pas gérer les
> interfaces

I had the same problem and I returned a `java.util.List<RelationCanonical[]>` in the declaration of the web method, I got a `java.util.List<RelationCanonicalArray>` in the client side code and I just had to call `RelationCanonicalArray.getItem()` to get a `java.util.List<RelationCanonical>`. I tested with Jakarta EE 9.1 with Wildfly 26.1.1. Henning's answer is correct but when `RelationCanonical` is already supported by JAXB, why driving things so much more complicated?

Answer (score -6):

You can use "ArrayList" instead of inner "List"

Comment: Yes I already mentioned in the question that I did this, but it still didn't work. Read the update

Comment: It doesn't work, it generates a class called ArrayList but it's not a java.util.ArrayList.