# JAX-WS, why LinkedHashMap collection received is empty?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I am building a java webservice which receive a `LinkedHashMap` as argument. The `LinkedHashMap` collection has some elements inserted in the client side, but I received it empty in the webservice.

Answer (score 1):

> Avoid returning collections directly. Instead of returning a `List<X>`, return a JavaBean that has a `List<X>` in it. This will give you more detailed control over the marshalling anyway.

[*Producing a Web Service with JAX-WS and JAXB*](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Producing+a+Web+Service+with+JAX-WS+and+JAXB)

See also:

- [What happens to generic class in jax-ws webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298914/870248)