# Objects stored in LinkedList<T>s can't survive JAX-WS RPC calls?

Tags: java, xml, jax-ws, xml-rpc

During development of an server/client application which uses JAX-WS RPC-style XML, I found that any time I used a `LinkedList<T>` as a parameter or return type over JAX-WS, the contents of said `LinkedList<T>` would vanish.

I wrote up an example program to demonastrate the issue. In this application, a new Server "Vegeta" is created which can be asked a question by a client "Nappa". Sentences, which are each a `LinkedList<Word>`, are passed between them via JAX-WS RPC. These `LinkedList<Word>` objects always arrive at the other side empty.

**Does anyone know why this happens?**

If it helps, my demonstration code is below. Any and all answers will be greatly appreciated.

*Interface IServer is the interface used by Nappa to talk to Vegeta:*

```
package com.stuffvegetasays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface IServer 
{
    @WebMethod abstract LinkedList<Word> answer(LinkedList<Word> question);
}
```

*Class Vegeta implements IServer (and as such acts as a server) passes itself to Nappa so that Nappa can use RPC to access it's methods*

```
package com.stuffvegetasays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.stuffvegetasays.IServer")
public class Vegeta implements IServer
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Vegeta vegeta = new Vegeta();

        System.out.println("Starting Server");
        String serverAddress = "http://0.0.0.0:9000/Vegeta";
        Endpoint serverEnd = Endpoint.create(vegeta);
        serverEnd.publish(serverAddress);
        System.out.println("Server Published!");
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedList<Word> answer(LinkedList<Word> question) 
    {
        System.out.println(question);
        LinkedList<Word> answer = new LinkedList<Word>();
        answer.add(new Word("\n\n"));
        answer.add(new Word("It's "));
        answer.add(new Word("over "));
        answer.add(new Word("NINE "));
        answer.add(new Word("THOUSAND!!!"));
        return answer;
    }
}
```

*Class Nappa acts as the client, making calls to Vegeta's URL.*

```
package com.stuffvegetasays;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class Nappa
{
    // Do an RPC style call to the published server "Vegeta".
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL serverURL;
        try 
        {
        serverURL = new URL("http://localhost:9000/Vegeta/");
        QName appServerQName = new QName("http://stuffvegetasays.com/", "VegetaService");

        Service service = Service.create(serverURL, appServerQName);

        IServer vegeta = service.getPort(IServer.class);

        LinkedList<Word> question = new LinkedList<Word>();
        question.add(new Word("Vegeta! "));
        question.add(new Word("What "));
        question.add(new Word("does "));
        question.add(new Word("the "));
        question.add(new Word("scouter "));
        question.add(new Word("say "));
        question.add(new Word("about "));
        question.add(new Word("his "));
        question.add(new Word("power "));
        question.add(new Word("level?"));

        System.out.println(question);
        LinkedList<Word> quote = vegeta.answer(question);
        System.out.println(quote);
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*Class Word is just a container for a String with a modified toString() method.*

```
package com.stuffvegetasays;

public class Word
{
    String value;

    public Word(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Avoid returning collections directly. Instead of returning a `List<X>`, return a JavaBean that has a `List<X>` in it. This will give you more detailed control over the marshalling anyway.

[*Producing a Web Service with JAX-WS and JAXB*](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Producing+a+Web+Service+with+JAX-WS+and+JAXB)

See also:

- [What happens to generic class in jax-ws webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298914/870248)

Comment: If the question is a duplicate please vote to close rather than posting either a duplicate answer or an answer that consists of a link to another Stack Overflow question.