# Cannot Discover QNAme from JAXB for class: java.util.Map

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, jaxb, wadl

I am trying to use a **Spring Wadl Generator**: https://github.com/autentia/wadl-tools.

AFAIK, this tool uses the same idea of the [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.de/2012/02/automatically-generating-wadl-in-spring.html) @tomasz-nurkiewicz: get the RequestMappingHandlerMapping from Spring, inspect each element and generate a appropriate WADL.

Internally, the tool will use JAXB to create an XML of the parameters in controllers. As far as good, but things doesn't run nicely with my application.

I got the following exception:

```
2014-02-07 15:33:41,827 WARN  user=unauthenticatedUser com.autentia.xml.namespace.QNameBuilder  - Cannot discover QName from JAXB annotations for class: java.util.Map. Preparing generic QName.com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.Map is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.Map
```

Which comes from (simplified stacktrack)

```
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:471)
    (...)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    (...)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
at com.autentia.xml.namespace.QNameBuilder.discoverQNameFromJaxb(QNameBuilder.java:68)
    (...)
at com.autentia.web.rest.wadl.builder.ApplicationBuilder.build(ApplicationBuilder.java:36)
```

**The question**

Could I force a default adapter to an Interface?

Normally people can just put annotations for interface with specific Adapter but *I don't wanna change* and/or analyze hundred of classes.

**Related links**

- [java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298733/java-util-list-is-an-interface-and-jaxb-cant-handle-interfaces)
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html
- https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/06/06/jaxb-and-interfaces

### Edited

Unfortunately I cannot change REST API.

From [javadoc of MessageWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html):

> Contract for a provider that supports the conversion of a Java type to a stream. To add a  MessageBodyWriter implementation, annotate the implementation class with @Provider.

WADL should provide info of services as they are. Adding a MessageBodyWriter via annotation for example  would change the API.  Since I can change QNameBuilder.discoverQNameFromJaxb, would there be possible change/provide in this very "moment" the MessageBodyWriter to java.util.Map and change back WADL generation?

Answer (score 3):

### What's Causing the Problem

JAXB (JSR-222) implementations can handle `java.util.Map` as a mapped field/property, but can not handle it as a root level object.  You probably have a method corresponding to a RESTful operation that returns to takes a `Map`.

### How to Solve It

1. Instead of having `Map` as the root level object you could introduce a new domain object that has a mapped field/property of type `Map` and use that instead.
2. Implement a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` for the `Map` class so that will be used instead of JAXB being used.

---

### UPDATE

> I don't wanna change and analyze hundred of classes

You wouldn't be.  You would simply be adding a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` that recognizes the `Map` class (for the "application/xml" media type) to do special handling for it.  The alternative is to keep getting an exception.

> Basically I cannot change the REST API.

You wouldn't be changing the REST API.  You would need to ensure that your `MessageBodyReader`/`MessaggeBodyWriter` works appropriately.

> By using a low level of dark magic, would be possible supply a
>   MessageBodyWriter for the Map and remove after that?

It's not really all that low level or dark magic.  You can supply special handling just for the `Map` class.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change REST API. WADL should provide info of services as they are. (I will add more info in question).

Comment: I've updated the question making more clear what I mean by " I don't wanna change and analyze hundred of classes". Basically I cannot change the REST API.  By using a low level of dark magic, would be possible supply a MessageBodyWriter for the Map and remove after that?

Comment: @blaise.doughan - as long as go deep this I realize how complicated it could be. I am using Spring MVC that AFAIK, out of box it will not identify \@Provider Annotation (Actually, JSR 311 which contains MessageBodyWriter it was currently in CLASSPATH also).

Comment: The big issue about that solution is the @Provider annotation. I need to add JSR 311 + provide a way to Spring understand this annotation.