# Glassfish 4.0 Exception while loading the app, java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: web-services, glassfish

I am new to web services and glassfish.  Here is my code

```
package ws.mypkg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public class TestRPC {

    // This seems to cause the problem when a List is returned.
    public List<String> testRPC () {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("Hello");
        return l;
    }

    // This method work fine
    public String testRPC1 () {
        return "Testing RPC";
    }
}
```

If I have

```
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
```

I get the following error when I try to deploy the web service.

> cannot Deploy TestGF deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception
>       while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>       org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service
>        endpoint '' failure. Please see server.log for more details.

Server log does not have anything more.

It deploys fine when I comment out `@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)`

The problem appears to be with the first method.  If I exclude the first method, the second method deploys fine.  It seems like I am having this problem when I return a list from the method and I have `@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)`

I am using Glassfish 4.0, jdk 1.7 and Eclipse (bundled in with Spring 3.4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your method return type is an interface and `JAXB` cannot work with interfaces because it doesn't know which `List` implementation to use.

To fix it just change the return type of method to `ArrayList` like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> testRPC () {
    ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("Hello");
    return l;
}
```

As the error message suggests, more info can be found in the `server.log`. There should be something like:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.List
```

This should point you in the right direction if similar errors occur.

**See also:**

- [java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298733/java-util-list-is-an-interface-and-jaxb-cant-handle-interfaces)

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the List to ArrayList.  It deployed OK.  But when I run, the response appears to return an empty object.  All I see <return/>.  However, if I take away the RPC style, I see the list returned as <return>Hello</return>